# Error reading 'indexUser' on type com.bean.Beans

Tags: spring, jsf

the variable indexUser exists in the com.bean.Beans, and when I run my program he said he just can not read the variable, then it exists.
I don't know what to do to solve this problem.

the error :

```
/pages/User.xhtml @18,60 value="#{beans.indexUser}": Error reading 'indexUser' on type com.bean.Beans
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:164)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:75)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:71)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:52)
```

code class Manager :

```
@ManagedBean(name="beans")
@Scope
@Component
public class Beans {
 @ManagedProperty(value="#{indexUser}")
      public Integer indexUser;

        public Integer getIndexUser() {
            Session session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            int index = 0;
            try {
                session.beginTransaction();
                String sql = "select MAX(t.IDTICKET) from ticket t ";
                Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
                if( query.uniqueResult()==null){

                    index=0;
                }else{

                    index=(int) query.uniqueResult();
                    index=index+1;
                }
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return indexUser= index;
        }
```

the view code :

```
<p:inputText value="#{beans.indexUser}" style="width:201px; height:20px; font-size:15px;" />
```

Comment: That method just threw an exception. You should look at bottommost exception in the stack trace for the root cause. You've by the way a severe design problem by performing business logic in a getter method.

Comment: BalusC : every compilation of my code a exeception mentioned explicitly because of that the

Comment: You didn't seem to understand me. Ok, let's put it differently: edit your question to post the **entire** stack trace.